# POSTing Form Data and Storing Cookie File with PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

```
$process = curl_init();

$temporary_cookie_file = 'temporaryfiles/'.strtolower($user_general_information['Username']).'_cookies.txt';
$temporary_cookie_file_handler = fopen($temporary_cookie_file, 'w');
fclose($temporary_cookie_file_handler);

$user_data = array('TCNK'=>'authenticationEntryComponent', 'submitEvent'=>'1', 'guestLoginEvent'=>'', 'enterClicked'=>'true', 'bscf'=>'', 'bscv'=>'', 'targetEntid'=>'', 'ajaxSupported'=>'yes', 'screenName'=>$user_general_information['Username'], 'kclq'=>$user_general_information['Password']);

curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.edline.net/post/InterstitialLogin.page');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Chrome/12.0.742.122');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($user_data));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($temporary_cookie_file));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($temporary_cookie_file));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$results_1 = curl_exec($process);

var_dump($results_1);
die();
```

I am trying to use POST form data to log into a site and then store the created cookies in a temporary file. I've looked at other discussions that talk about doing this and did as them but it doesn't work. When I try, it simply refreshes the page with no changes. I've been working on this for hours...Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For note, the cookies from the first site are required for the second site.

Comment: It looks like both requests are to the same site.  In this case, you should be using the same cookie file for both curl requests.  Since you're re-using the same curl handle, it may not be necessary to store the cookies in a file (unless you want them to persist) as curl will track cookies within the handle without having to save them to a file.

Comment: @drew010 I don't believe they are the same site. But I tested it out by deleting the first request altogether, and still got redirected back to the login screen of the second site instead of being logged in.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, both URL's are on www.edline.net so they are the same site?

Comment: most of those curl_setopt calls are redundant. once you set an option, they generally STAY set, unless some other option implicitly changes it. you don't need to set the user agent, followlocation,etc... each time.

Comment: Right but they are different pages. What's supposed to happen is you get "pre-logged-in" cookies from one page which are then used on the second page. But, anyway, even just going to the second directly and submit POST form data, it doesn't work. Any ideas on why?

Comment: @drew010 After investigation, I discovered it doesn't actually matter, but that the site still won't work. Any ideas now?

Comment: Their login form has a csrf token field (`csrfToken`) which you'll need to extract from the initial login page and include with your post.  That's at the very least why it isn't working now.